# Escape apostrophe character in a list in XSLT

Tags: xslt

How can I use the apostrophe `'` character in a list? The following code fails, because the list contains an unescaped character in word "Fruit's 13". I tried escape it by backslash character and also by ', but none of them worked.

```
<xsl:param name="unsorted-values" as="xs:string*" select="'Apple','Banana','Fruit's 13'"/>
    
    <xsl:param name="values" as="xs:string*">
        <xsl:perform-sort select="$unsorted-values">
            <xsl:sort select="string-length()" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:param>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath 2 and later in string literal delimited by single quotes (apostrophs) you can double `''` a single quote/apostroph to have it escaped inside the string value, most attributes of XSLT like `select` use XPath expressions so there you can use that syntax.

Of course in the context of XSLT/XML you could also use `select="'Apple', 'Banana', &quot;Fruit's 13&quot;"`.

XPath 3.1 syntax section for that is in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#prod-xpath31-StringLiteral.